# Is there a better method to structure this if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

It just seems a mess to me, my mind tells me there has to be a better way.

I have 6 controls on a web page.

```
if (printer_make_1.Text != "" && printer_model_1.Text != "" && printer_make_2.Text != "" && printer_model_2.Text != "" && printer_make_3.Text != "" && printer_model_3.Text != "")
{
  // Do something
}
```

What is the best/most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your code is perfectly readable and almost certainly correct. Is there some business advantage to changing readable, correct code?

Comment: if I have to use an if statement like this more than once I definitely turn it into a method as others have suggested, otherwise I'd leave it as is

Comment: @EricLippert no advantage but furthering my own knowledge.  I've definitely learned quite a few new ways to do this, my two favorites so far are the method option and the class option.

Comment: And it was less readable until @TimBJames fixed it up in an edit for me. ;)

Comment: Man I wish I could give two answers on this one. =(

Comment: @JamesWilson, I've rolled back the edit to your original version as the edit is potentially a valid answer and your original code is what you're trying to make more readable/better structured =) You should (I think!) be able to do that yourself OR change it back to TimBJames's version if you wish by clicking on the "edit" link underneath your question =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restructuring starts with your data: avoid `printer_make_1`, `printer_make_2`, ...

```
class PrinterData
{
   public string Make { get; set; }
   public string Model { get; set; }
}

PrinterData[] printers = new PrinterData[3];  //or use a List<>

printers[0] = new PrinterData { Make = "PH", Model = "1A" };
...

if (printers.All(p => ! (p.Make == "" || p.Model == "")) )
  ...
```

Comment: If I allow them to fill out three different printer make/models, would I just create 4 more properties?  I'm pretty new to asp.net.

Comment: @Henk: If you're makin' a class of it, you can use a property `HasValue` for readability as well, like `public bool HasValue { get { return !(Make.Length == 0 || Model.Length == 0); } }`

Comment: No printers is a List. I'll make it an array, that's easier to grasp.

Comment: @HenkHolterman which method would you say is better?  Array or List or are they so close it's personal choice?  If list is better is there a good read out there that you know of that can help me understand how to use list in this fashion better?  Just trying to learn the most I can. :)

Comment: I would almost always use a List<>, but you seem to have a very fixed number(3) of elements so an array is OK too.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman I'll try and find a good tutorial out there to help me understand how to use list's better, never really touched them.

Comment: To be honest, I overlooked the .Text properties, ie that this is about controls. The answer is still mostly valid.

Comment: I would just do `new PrinterData { Make = printer_make_1.Text, Model = printer_model_2.Text }` right?

Comment: I picked this one because I like the Object Oriented approach to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can refactor into a method, if you want to improve the readability or use the same logic elsewhere:

```
public Boolean AllControlsHaveAValue() {
    return (printer_make_1.Text != ""
        && printer_model_1.Text != ""
        && printer_make_2.Text != ""
        && printer_model_2.Text != ""
        && printer_make_3.Text != ""
        && printer_model_3.Text != "");
}
```

Then just ask:

```
if (AllControlsHaveAValue()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 The problem isn't necessarily the structure of the if or the need to write it another way, sometimes it just makes sense to wrap it in a method name that is readable. Reminds me of commentless programming.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Mmmm...commentless code :) I think Spolsky wrote a great article about that a while ago.

Comment: @Yuck: there's this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/coding-without-comments.html

Comment: @Yuck Yeah that's probably what I'm remembering. I don't got for it in the purist sense, but sometimes it makes a lot of sense... complicated if statements are the most prevalent.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(new[] { printer_make_1, printer_model_1 ...}.All(l => l.Text != string.Empty)
{
    //do something
}
```

You might want to split it up to be more readable:

```
var labels = new[] { printer_make_1, printer_model_1 ... };
if(labels.All(l => l.Text != string.Empty))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Haha, that is hardly more readable...IMHO. Certainly does the trick though.

Comment: This one definitely made me smile.

Comment: While that will work. I don't see how that's the "best/most efficient way to do this". I think to OP version is more readable, and readability creates maintainability which IMHO makes is better.

Comment: @C.Dragon76 - Less efficient maybe, but it looks more readable to me, and is easily extensible.

Answer (score 2):

I normally put that test into a method and call that to make the if easier to read

```
private boolean AreAllPrinterFieldsFilled()
{
    return (printer_make_1.Text != "" 
        && printer_model_1.Text != "" 
        && printer_make_2.Text != "" 
        && printer_model_2.Text != "" 
        && printer_make_3.Text != "" 
        && printer_model_3.Text != "");
}
```

Then in the if:

```
if (AreAllPrinterFieldsFilled)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this - none of them are elegant. **Do what is most readable to you (and those who may come behind you).**

I would probably take this approach:

```
string makeText = String.Concat(printer_make_1.Text, printer_make_2.Text, printer_make_3.Text);
string modelText = String.Concat(printer_model_1.Text, printer_model_2.Text, printer_model_3.Text);

if (makeText.Length != 0 && modelText.Length != 0)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Why create a few new strings just to check the values of a few existing ones?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer, the creation of a few strings is trivial. Again, there are **lots** of ways to accomplish this (as I stated). For me, this is the most readable/understandable. I don't think the creation of a few strings will cause any performance issues :)

Comment: I'm not really disputing the performance impact.  I guess I am just sympathetic to Eric Lippert's comment on the question implying that if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .Any(i => ((TextBox)FindControl("printer_make_" + i)).Text == "" || 
        ((TextBox)FindControl("printer_model_" + i)).Text == "") {...}
```

It allows you to later expand the number of printer makes and models, but isn't as strong typed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool CheckAllEmpty(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    return textBoxes.All(tb => tb.Text != null);
}

private void Foo()
{
    ...

    if (CheckAllEmpty(tb1, tb2, tb3))
    {
        mbox("tb1, tb2 and tb3 are all empty");
    }
    else
    {
        mbox("tb1, tb2 or tb3 isn't empty");
    }

    ...
}
```